# Java - List array of a static class returns always same values

Tags: java, arrays, list, static

I am trying to fill-in a static list of Arrays.
The function `RTTWifiPositionsToJava` is used from Unity (C#) to pass the Parameters for each WifiPosition.
But **each** item of the list `m_RTTWifiPositions` has the same value as the last added value.
Can somebody help please, thanks :)

```
static class RTTWifiPos
{  
    static String strMacAddress;
    static double posX, posY, posZ;
    static double distance; 
    static double distanceDev;
}

static List<RTTWifiPos> m_RTTWifiPositions;

public static boolean RTTWifiPositionsToJava(int nIndex, String strMacAddress, double PosX, double PosY, double PosZ, double distance, double distanceStdDev)
{  
    if(nIndex == 0)
    {
       if(m_RTTWifiPositions != null)  
            m_RTTWifiPositions.clear();
       else
            m_RTTWifiPositions = new ArrayList<RTTWifiPos>();
    }
    RTTWifiPos rttpos = new RTTWifiPos();

    rttpos.strMacAddress = strMacAddress;
    rttpos.posX = PosX;
    rttpos.posY = PosY;
    rttpos.posZ = PosZ;
    rttpos.distance = distance;
    rttpos.distanceDev = distanceStdDev;

    m_RTTWifiPositions.add(rttpos);

    return true;
}
```

The function `RTTWifiPositionsToJava` is called from Unity3D like this:

```
for (nIndex = 0; nIndex < WifiRTTSignals.Count; nIndex++)
{
    result = m_pluginWifiRTTClass.CallStatic<bool>("RTTWifiPositionsToJava", nIndex, WifiRTTSignals[nIndex].macAddress, (double) WifiRTTSignals[nIndex].pos.x, (double) WifiRTTSignals[nIndex].pos.y, (double) WifiRTTSignals[nIndex].pos.z, (double) WifiRTTSignals[nIndex].distance, (double) 0f);
}
```

Comment: You've *almost* answered your own question. Take a look into the `static` context in java. Hint: should `strMacAddress` and other variables be `static`?

Comment: You haven't initialized the List m_RTTWifiPositions, though that should have thrown an error.

Comment: @NomadMaker I'm betting there's some other code, maybe a constructor, that initializes it. Otherwise `m_RTTWifiPositions.add(rttpos);` would throw a NPE.

Comment: Could you please provide the code where you're calling `RTTWifiPositionsToJava()` as well? Side note: Please try to stay conform with the [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf) (Edit: Yes, the PDF is old, but should still suffice for this case) to improve readability, that uppercase method name might cause confusion.

Comment: Thank you for your Reply all.
I have now edited the Code to make it more clear.
many thanks

Comment: This is where list is cleared every time `if(m_RTTWifiPositions != null)  
        m_RTTWifiPositions.clear();` After each call list contains only last element.

Comment: Thank you Yury,
you are absolutely Right. I edited the Code again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in RTTWifiPos will always be the same becus the are static. Static variables will always have the same value independent of objects [explanation](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/). Example:

```
static class RTTWifiPos
{  
    String strMacAddress;
    double posX, posY, posZ;
    double distance; 
    double distanceDev;
}
```

I would also make them private and with getter/setter methods instead for [better control](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/143739).

Comment: Thank you flaimme,
I thought by using `RTTWifiPos rttpos = new RTTWifiPos();` everything is having a new instance ? But I will follow your and sleepToken's hint.

Comment: By using `RTTWifiPos rttpos = new RTTWifiPos();` you got a new object but the variables declared static will be the same as for all the objects of the same type.